# why ReactTestUtil 's act() is designed to not return a promise when the callback function doens't return a value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

below is the method signatures of ReactTestUtil's `act()`

```
export function act(callback: () => VoidOrUndefinedOnly): void;        // Part A
export function act<T>(callback: () => T | Promise<T>): Promise<T>;    // Part B
```

I can understand Part B, but for Part A, there is no return of `Promise<void>` if we do something like:

```
act(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(<ComplicatedComponent />, document.createElement("div"));
});
```

where `ComplicatedComponent` is a component that consumes a lot of time to render in dom

So I cannot use async/await like:

```
// warning: 'await' has no effect on the type of this expression

await act(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(<ComplicatedComponent />, document.createElement("div"));
});
```

so I have to return something to make it return a Promise as:

```
// OK now

await act(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(<ComplicatedComponent />, document.createElement("div"));
    return null;
});
```

so why `act()` is designed to not return a promise when the callback function doens't return a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ReactTestUtils provides both syncronous and asyncronous versions of `act`.

Calling `act` like so

```
act(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(<ComplicatedComponent />, document.createElement("div"));
});
```

runs syncronously (it'll block the thread until the component has been rendered), and as such, it doesn't return a promise and you shouldn't `await` it.

If you pass in an async callback however

```
await act(async () => {
    ReactDOM.render(<ComplicatedComponent />, document.createElement("div"));
});
```

then the top-level `act` will now return a promise, and can be awaited, etc.

---

Here's the PR where they implemented this behaviour: https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/14853

---

The types are just explaining the same thing: if you return anything from the callback (which happens automatically when you add `async` before the callback, it now returns a `Promise<void>` rather than `void`), then they switch to the async version of `act`, and as a result you will be able to await it, so it returns a promise in that case.